# Flutter how to make widget height adjust to content?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a product page, I need it to scroll and my `DefaultTabController` to change its height depending on the text that is inside, now I set a fixed height, how can I make it adjust itself?

```
Widget buildProduct({required ProductItem product, required context}) {
  final media = product.media!.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
  var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: mediaQuery.height * 0.4,
            child: ImageList()
        ),
        Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                product.name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
              Text(
                product.categoryName!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Text(
                '${product.price} ₸',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
        SizedBox(
          height: 260.h,
          child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 35.h,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  child: const TabBar(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 5.0),
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: 'О товаре'),
                      Tab(text: 'В наличии'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          child: product.description != null
                              ? Html(data: product.description, style: {
                            'body': Style(
                              fontSize: FontSize(14.0),
                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                  .colorScheme
                                  .onSecondary,
                            ),
                          })
                              : const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Описание отсутствует',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                            ),
                          )),
                      Container(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text('В наличии'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Comment: put ur DefaultTabController inside of FittedBox. SizedBox( height:... , childe:FittedBox(child:DefaultTabController  ))

Comment: it's not working i got this error `RenderBox was not laid out`